# Python Pandas groupby data on a "list" column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hi I have a list column in my data-frame and would like group by values in the list. Below is the piece of code and expected output

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame([ { "id" : "1", "fix": ["fix1", "fix2"] }, { "id" : "2", "fix": ["fix2", "fix3"] } ])
res=df.groupby(["fix"]).count() /* this does not work */
```

Output

```
fix1 - 1
fix2- 2  
fix3 -1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) first:

```
res=df.explode('fix').groupby(["fix"]).count() 
print (res)
fix     
fix1   1
fix2   2
fix3   1
```

Similar solution with [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) and [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
res=df['fix'].explode().value_counts()
print (res)
fix2    2
fix3    1
fix1    1
Name: fix, dtype: int64
```